# Strange behaviour in template expansion and HTML inclusion

Tags: w3.css

I'm playing with w3.css and want to expand a template and include some
HTML. The example is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>BUG</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css"/>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="w3-container">

    <div id="id03">
      <div w3-repeat="customers">
    <p>Here: img = {{CustomerName}} text={{City}} country={{Country}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div w3-include-html="include.html"></div>

  </div>
  <script>
    w3IncludeHTML();

    var myObject = {"customers":[
      {"CustomerName":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
      {"CustomerName":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"},
      {"CustomerName":"Chop-suey Chinese","City":"Bern","Country":"Switzerland"}
      ]};

      w3DisplayData("id03", myObject);

  </script>

</body>

  </html>
```

and the included file (include.html) is

```
 <div>
   <h1>I am included</h1>
   <button class="w3-btn w3-white w3-border">Button</button>
 </div>
```

If I comment out the w3IncludeHTML line the program works as I expect
but with this line included the expansion is incorrect and the file
included twice.

And ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The w3IncludeHTML() is as follows

```
   function w3IncludeHTML() {
       var z, i, a, file, xhttp;
       z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
       for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
          if (z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html")) {
                a = z[i].cloneNode(false);
                file = z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html");
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                     a.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
                     a.innerHTML = this.responseText;          
                     z[i].parentNode.replaceChild(a, z[i]);
                     w3IncludeHTML();
                 }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
            xhttp.send();
            return;
        }
     }
  }
```

Before the XMLHTTPRequest(XHR) gets the successful response our element `<div w3-include-html="include.html"></div>` resides at the position `i`. Since the XHR requests are asynchrounous, the `w3DisplayData("id03", myObject)` is executed before the onreadystatechange callback.

`w3DisplayData` manipulates the DOM so our position is occupied by another DOM element.

Upon receiving the Successsfull XHR response `i` has been used again to refer the element `<div w3-include-html="include.html"></div>`. Due to the DOM manipulation the `i`th position is been occupied by other element so the content of the include.html becomes a child to `<div id="id03">`

The duplicate insertion of `<div w3-include-html="include.html"></div>` is because of a call to `w3IncludeHTML()` in onreadystatechange callback.

This behaviour can be fixed by replacing the `w3IncludeHtml` code as follows

```
     function w3IncludeHTML() {
         var z, i, a, file, xhttp;
         z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
         for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            if (z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html")) {
                  a = z[i].cloneNode(false);
                  file = z[i].getAttribute("w3-include-html");
                  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  nodeToReplace = z[i]
                  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                           a.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
                           a.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                           nodeToReplace.parentNode.replaceChild(a, nodeToReplace);
                           w3IncludeHTML();
                     }
                 }
                 xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
                 xhttp.send();
                 return;
           }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Great - thank you very much. I thought it was something like that. I wonder how one can report a bug to W3Schools?